# Android: Proguard rules for dependencies and modules

Tags: android, dependencies, proguard

I have a project with a couple of modules, some jar dependencies in libs folder and some some other gradle dependencies. I am trying to build a release apk with proguard enabled but i am getting a lot of warnings during the build process for certain dependencies. e.g this:

```
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider: can't find superclass or interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
```

Would someone please refer a guide on how to properly define rules for the dependencies. and do i need to add rules for the modules besides the **app** module.

**Edit:**

I have added the following rule to the app build.gradle file:

```
-keep interface org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
```

but i am still getting the warnings during build process.

Comment: are you getting any crash while running apk from progaurd?

Comment: please post your gradle file.Just wanna know which version of Jackson you are using.Also are you sure if it is related to Jackson processor?

Comment: @diva The build process fails because of the warnings.

Comment: are you using any lib in ur code?

Comment: @goonerdroid I have fixed the problem with jackson. but i still have some issues left with a couple of other dependencies. e.g retrofit which i am not even using directly. its used by another library that i am referencing

Comment: @diva offcourse i am using a lot of them. its a pretty big project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this rule for retrofit

```
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
```

and my jackson rules are

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
 -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
 public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class your.class.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
}
```

EDIT

Your library jars refer to yet more library jars (Mortbay, SLF4J, Apache Commons Logging, Log4j, ...) Adding these jars with extra '-libraryjars' options should solve the problem.If you are not refrencing them then use this rule

```
-dontwarn javax.management.**  
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**  
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**  
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.** 
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**  
-dontwarn org.json.*
```

Comment: Thanks @goonerdroid. The retrofit rules worked but there is one more warning now  Warning:oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Comment: and if the build succeeds, does that mean everything is fine or should i expect runtime issues ?

Comment: As far as it compiles without any warnings or errors ,you won't get any runtime errors

Comment: Thanks for the response. but i am still getting the same error even after including the above statements.

Comment: -keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }

Comment: Thanks. I am going to accept this answer since it answers my original question. I am still having issues with oauth but i will post another question for that. I'll post a link to the question please have a look at it then. Thanks

Comment: here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560781/proguard-error-android-oauth-signpost-signature