# Proguard error android - oauth.signpost.signature

Tags: android, proguard

I am getting this error during build process

```
Warning:oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

Its a jar file inside the libs folder that i am using inside my project.

**Edit:** Here is the build.gradle file but it doesn't include all the dependencies. I have some jars in the libs folder as well.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 54
        versionName "2.002"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
        resConfigs "en", "fr" , "ar"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    repositories{
        maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
        compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
        compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.+'
        compile project(':Adjust')
        compile project(':aFileChooser-cbccac1d1cb74a6d57d25c5ded61e4bf4fc40c91')
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile (group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.0.0.1'){
            //    exclude group:'picasso'
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.+'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'

        androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
        androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
        androidTestCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19')

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}



robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
}
```

**Update:** i am able to build the project now using the rules specified by @goonerdroid but it crashes on startup with NoClassDefFound error for my MainActivity

Comment: Post your gradle files,just to understand what all libraries you are using

Comment: @goonerdroid I have edited the question. SO went on to readonly mode for a while so i couldn't post it.

Answer (score 1):

try these rules

```
-dontwarn org.mortbay.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
```

Comment: Still getting errors for some other classes in the same package. Its a jar file that i am referencing inside my project. Don't you think ignoring this would cause runtime exceptions ?

Comment: update : i am able to build the project Now but it crashes on startup with NoClassDefFound error for my MainActivity

Comment: Add these jars with extra '-libraryjars' options

Comment: i already have -libraryjars libs in my proguard rules. Are you talking about this. and it seems like its a problem with multidex + proguard. I have posted a question. Please look at the edited section in the end http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563803/android-proguard-classnotfoundexception?noredirect=1#comment45439496_28563803