# Android Proguard - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I enabled proguard for my android app. I can build the project successfully but it crashes on startup with classNotFoundException. It doesn't even find the launcher activity. Here is my proguard rules file

```
-libraryjars libs

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-keepnames class com.mypackage.** { *; } //someone suggested this but doesn't work

# We only want obfuscation
-keepattributes InnerClasses,Signature

# Sdk
-keep public interface com.zendesk.sdk.** { *; }
-keep public class com.zendesk.sdk.** { *; }

# Appcompat and support
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

# Gson
-keep interface com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }

# Retrofit
#-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
#-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
#-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
#-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
#-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
#-keep interface retrofit.** { *; }

# Retrofit
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

# Jackson
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
 -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
 public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class your.class.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
}

#Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

#-dontwarn javax.management.**
#-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
#-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
#-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
#-dontwarn org.json.*
#-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

#-keep class javax.** {* ; }
#-keep class org.** { *; }

-dontwarn org.mortbay.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
```

and here is my build.gradle file if that helps but it doesn't include all the dependencies. I have some jars in the libs folder as well.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 54
        versionName "2.002"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
        resConfigs "en", "fr" , "ar"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    repositories{
        maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
        compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
        compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.+'
        compile project(':Adjust')
        compile project(':aFileChooser-cbccac1d1cb74a6d57d25c5ded61e4bf4fc40c91')
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile (group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.0.0.1'){
            //    exclude group:'picasso'
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.+'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'


        /*compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2') {
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
            exclude module: 'httpcore'
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
        }
        compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2') {
            exclude module: 'commons-codec'
        }*/

        androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
        androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
        androidTestCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19')

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}



robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
}
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): Process: com.mypackage, PID: 2079
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mypackage/activities/MainActivity;
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at cmypackage.application.ApplicationContextProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mypackage.activities.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mypackage-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     ... 12 more
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage.activities.MainActivity
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         ... 14 more
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.MainActivity
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):         ... 13 more
02-17 19:01:09.752: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

**Edit:** Below is the missing part from the stacktrace.

```
02-17 19:01:09.749: I/MultiDex(2079): VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
02-17 19:01:09.749: I/MultiDex(2079): install
02-17 19:01:09.749: I/MultiDex(2079): VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
02-17 19:01:09.750: I/art(2079): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity>
02-17 19:01:09.750: I/art(2079): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity>
02-17 19:01:09.751: I/art(2079): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<mypackage.activities.MainActivity>
02-17 19:01:09.751: I/art(2079): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<mypackage.activities.MainActivity>
02-17 19:01:09.751: D/AndroidRuntime(2079): Shutting down VM
02-17 19:01:09.751: D/AndroidRuntime(2079): --------- beginning of crash
```

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace from logcat.

Comment: @Trinimon posted the stack trace

Comment: I guess everything works fine if you disable proguard right?

Comment: exactly. and there is something i missed in the stack trace. I am editing the question to add that. It might give you a clue

Comment: @Trinimon edited my question. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to also make sure to add in the New Relic proguard exceptions found here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/mobile-monitoring-installation/android/installing-android-apps-gradle-android-studio#proguard

```
-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. It worked :) but while trying it in Debug build. I have to build the project every time because the execution fails with :app:retraceDebugMainDexClassList FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:retraceDebugMainDexClassList'.
> unable to read mapping file.                           Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Using `minifyEnabled true` for debug builds isn't really doing you a lot of good. Does setting that to false for debug builds remove the error?

Comment: I just wanted to test it on debug version. Thats fine now. but cant build with proguard-android-optimize.txt. it works with proguard-android.txt though

Comment: Well, in your build.gradle you have specified proguard-android.txt and not proguard-android-optimize.txt for release and debug build types. That's probably why that doesn't work.

Comment: I meant to say that when i change the above to optimize.txt, the build fails.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a rather old post but I would like to highlight the following should it help someone in the future.

The `ClassNotFoundException` is an exception caused by applying name obfuscation to a class that's accessed using reflection. For example if ProGuard renames the class `MyClass`, which is accessed in the code like this: `Class.forName("MyClass");`, a `ClassNotFoundException` will be thrown if the string still refers to `MyClass`.

This is where we would need to add a `-keep` option in order for ProGuard to not rename that class;

`-keep class com.example.MyClass`

When using broad `-keep` options (ending with `.** { *; }`), you will instruct ProGuard not to shrink, optimize or obfuscate all classes and classmembers for the package name mentioned before the wildcards. This will eventually lead in a poorly optimized project. Therefore it's better to narrow down such `-keep` option to only target the missing class. In OP's example, the following error is thrown:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mypackage.activities.MainActivity"`

Adding a `-keep` option for the missing class like shown below will tackle this particular issue;

`-keep class mypackage.activities.MainActivity`

ProGuard can help you set up narrowed down `-keep` options if you add `-addconfigurationdebugging` to the configuration file, more details  on this feature is documented in the ProGuard manual, [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage).

Recently the [ProGuard Playground](https://playground.proguard.com/) was released, you can quickly visualise the effect of the broad `-keep` options vs the narrowed down ones. A nice benefit here is that you do not need to continuously (re-)build the project.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the obfuscation rules related to activity and all also related to support libaries.Android studio by default has those templates.You could enable them by adding this rule in your gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
```

Also please edit the rule for Jackson processor

```
-keep public class your.class.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
}
```

In this your class.** is the POJO(getter/setter) class that you have created for parsing your response

Comment: I removed the rules. and edited the Jackson processor but still the same problem. I added the class thats referencing the jackson library to the above statement but didnt help

Comment: also about the buildType configurations. I am already doing that. I have added all the rules to  proguard-android.txt file

Comment: Thats right so why are you specifically adding android rules to your set of rules,remove them

Comment: yeah i have done that. Removed all the android related rules. but still getting the same problem.  My concern is this line in the logcat : VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled. I think this is a multidex problem. I had the same classNotfound exception before enabling multidex. After properly enabling multidex, i got rid of it but now after enabling proguard, i am getting the same problem