# Class Not Found Exception after export signed application android

Tags: android, eclipse, signed

Prior to uploading my signed APK to the playstore, I installed that on my phone. But it keeps on crashing saying class not found (I am having one class that extends Application). So I have this in my Manifest file:

```
<application
    android:name="Packagename.GlobalApplication"
```

I have already tried almost everything that I found on google regarding this issue and already wasted many hours.

I tried the following

- "fix project properties"
- clean and rebuild project
- deleting gen and bin folders and then again rebuild
- I don't have proguard enabled
- Restarting eclipse
- Checking manifest for correct package and application name

But Nothing really helped me !

And I have done this before for the same application before 4 days and it was working fine. Then I did some changes and again tried to export the signed application,  but its not working now.

Please someone help me out.

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: @Bunny : You have used progaurd in your application or not..??

Comment: Please check for the class, which is mentioned in the logcat(that's not found).

Comment: @AndiGeeky: I am not using proguard as I mentioned in my question

Comment: @AndiGeeky: I am using eclipse

Comment: @Bunny : Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/16636127/4018207

Comment: @AndiGeeky: I checked this answer but in my build path, android private library is already selected.

Comment: @Bunny : May i know which class can not be found runtime??

Comment: @AndiGeeky:  GlobalApplication.java which is extending Application

Comment: @AndiGeeky: Sometimes the launcher activity which is LogMeOnceActivity.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90395/discussion-between-andigeeky-and-bunny).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are obfuscated your code while export signed apk
refer this link

[Android Proguard - ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563803/android-proguard-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: I am not using proguard