# Navigation Library inflator throws ClassNotFoundException for data class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, kotlin-android-extensions, android-architecture-navigation

In the Navigation Library version alpha09+ (using alpha11) I am experiencing a ClassNotFoundException for one of my data classes which I defined as an argType in my navigation graph.

```
app:argType="com.package.app.data.model.user.User.Full"
```

This class does exist. When downgrading back to alpha08, the issue does not appear to happen.

This is the full stacktrace:

```
2019-01-28 10:30:32.028 6970-6970/com.package.app.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.package.app.debug, PID: 6970
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.app.debug/com.package.app.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.package.app.debug:navigation/navigation_main line 376
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:89)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:424)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:406)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:226)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1684)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1930)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3745)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387)
    at co.lokalise.android.sdk.core.LokaliseLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(LokaliseLayoutInflater.java:362)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at co.lokalise.android.sdk.core.LokaliseLayoutInflater.inflate(LokaliseLayoutInflater.java:84)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.package.app.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:75)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
2019-01-28 10:30:32.031 6970-6970/com.package.app.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.app.data.model.user.User.Full
    at androidx.navigation.NavType.fromArgType(NavType.java:180)
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflateArgument(NavInflater.java:181)
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflateArgumentForDestination(NavInflater.java:145)
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:120)
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:131)
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:80)
        ... 41 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.app.data.model.user.User.Full
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
    at androidx.navigation.NavType.fromArgType(NavType.java:168)
        ... 46 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.package.app.data.model.user.User.Full" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 50 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.package.app.debug-7IobagfWCqi3XccTjnUgwg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
2019-01-28 10:30:32.031 6970-6970/com.package.app.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
            ... 6 more
```

I have updated the Navigation Library component from alpha08 to alpha11. When they released alpha09, I also updated and had this same issue and thought it was a bug, so I waited. Now, the issue still persists and I can't seem to be able to figure out want went wrong.

I have already disabled ProGuard for debugging, as well as minify and have enabled Multidex to see if this would help.

```
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
    }
```

The class has also been added to the proguard-rules, to see if that would work.

```
-keep class com.package.app.data.model.** { *; }
```

As far as I'm concerned, this should work? Android Studio also generates the XML for me exactly like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After all, it was a known bug in Android Studio.

Since the release of 1.0.0-alpha09, something changed in the way they handled inner classes.

If a parcelable is an inner class, it has to be written like:
`com.domain.app.User$Full` where Full is the parcelized object.

If you want to read more about this, check out this answer on Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/123614632#comment4

Comment: It's a shame that still they didn't include this information in official doc.

Comment: Still this works for nav_version= 2.3.0-alpha02. Thanks man! 
I think it is easier to generate arguments directly from the design, rather going manually in text mode. 
This helps when we edit the nav_graph.xml code manually from Text mode and encounter such issue.

Comment: you save my life bro

Comment: You save me!. Thanks

Comment: This works not only for "inner" but also for "nested" classes...

Answer (score 9):

Just faced problem similar to this issue and I got realized I didn't set up any proguard rules. Here's additional information that might be helpful.

The following codes are found in navigation component version `2.2.0-rc02`.

```java
// NavType.java
try {
    String className;
    if (type.startsWith(".") && packageName != null) {
        className = packageName + type;
    } else {
        className = type;
    }

    if (type.endsWith("[]")) {
        className = className.substring(0, className.length() - 2);
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        if (Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new ParcelableArrayType(clazz);
        } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new SerializableArrayType(clazz);
        }
    } else {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        if (Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new ParcelableType(clazz);
        } else if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new EnumType(clazz);
        } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new SerializableType(clazz);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(className + " is not Serializable or "
            + "Parcelable.");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

You can see it looks for classes using `Class.forName(String)` method. So keeping their names is enough.

```
# Instead of -keep
-keepnames class com.package.app.data.model.** { *; }
```

And if `packageName` is provided, you can omit package name from value of argType attribute, but sadly it won't work if you use some application id suffixes depending on build variants. (So **do not omit package name** from argType)

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you you saved me so much time.  I ended up finding the right rules here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563803/android-proguard-classnotfoundexception

Comment: See also https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#proguard_considerations
and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139313440

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my argType was the class that was the Subclass of the fragment. I moved that class out of the fragment and problem was fixed

Comment: Hi! I've posted the correct answer on this issue. Completely forgot about my SO question, but it's there now. With some help from the Android team.